# how to filter a data frame based on a column value (country) in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I have a big data frame and I want to filter it according to the `COUNTRY` column. I need the data from European countries and I wrote :

```
country=['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Republic of Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 
'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 
'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 
'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain' , 'Sweden']
filtered_df = Data[Data.COUNTRY.isin(country)]'
```

but it doesn't show the rows of these mentioned countries in data frame! any idea?

Comment: Try `filtered_df = Data[Data.COUNTRY.str.isin(country)]`

Comment: Can you post a sample of the dataframe?

Comment: @thomask I got this :    StringMethods' object has no attribute 'isin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), here's an example using the iris dataset.

```
iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')
x1 = ['setosa', 'versicolor']
iris.query('species in @x1')
```

So for you it would be

```
Data.query('COUNTRY in @country')
```

Comment: `country=['Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Croatia', 'Republic of Cyprus', 'Czech 
    Republic', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Finland', 'France', 'Germany', 'Greece', 'Hungary', 
    'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Latvia', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 
    'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Slovakia', 'Slovenia', 'Spain' , 'Sweden']
     Data.query('species in @country')`

Comment: but it does not work!

Comment: see edit, `species` was a column within `iris`